# Windows service as insurance that my application server is running

Tags: c#, windows-services

I created a server application that always need to be online and running.

In case that my application is been shutdown i want to restart the application.

Is there a way that "Windows service" will be my online insurance?

If not is there another way?

Thanks.

Comment: Should it also be online if the datacenter gets flooded and all power goes off?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, windows services can be set to [restart if they fail.](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc742019%28v=ws.10%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

> In case that my application is been shutdown i want to restart the application.

This makes NO Sense and you should not do it.

If the admin shuts you down (and that is the only way a service is shut down) then he has a reason - maybe he has to apply emergency patches or something else.

If the app CRASHES that is another thing (and windows services can be set up to automatically restart when crashing), but if you geta  shutdown request do NOT restart as a service. Never. I can name you a dozen cases where it would be stupid - mostly around system maintenance that you would interfere with. You basically risk being terminated because the computer is switched off.

If your application is not a windows service you need to learn the basics how windows works, because it is ridiculously crappy to have a normal application act as sever process. For anything, a user must be interactively logged in. Next time I see a server with a logged in user because some stupid programmer could not do his job I promise I (censored).